# ERROR : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.axis.description.OperationDesc

Tags: java, axis, payara

**String[] arrayArgs = [p_UserID, STRING];
Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
call.addParameter(new QName(soapUrl, arrayArgs[0]),new QName(PMSConstants.PARAMETER_TYPE_HEAD + arrayArgs[1]), javax.xml.rpc.ParameterMode.IN);**

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.axis.description.OperationDesc    at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.addParameter(Call.java:968)   at
>   org.apache.axis.client.Call.addParameter(Call.java:944)   at
>   jp.co.hitachi_solutions.parasol.synvizmanagement.RISynVizManagementProvider.executeURL(RISynVizManagementProvider.java:235)
>   at
>   jp.co.hitachi_solutions.parasol.synvizmanagement.RISynVizManagementProvider.getProjectInfo(RISynVizManagementProvider.java:98)
>   at
>   jp.co.hitachi_solutions.parasol.synvizmanagement.RISynVizManagementBroker.getProjectInfo(RISynVizManagementBroker.java:27)
>   at
>   jp.co.hitachi_solutions.parasol.synvizmanagement.SynVizManagementServiceBean.getProjectInfo(SynVizManagementServiceBean.java:66)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)   at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:589)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:409)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4981)
>   at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:657) 
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:836)
>   at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:609)   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor122.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:895)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:835)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:374)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4953)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4941)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:205)
>   ... 56 more

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have to axis jar file in the classpath

Comment: The problem I want to ask is that when the program calls executeURL(), an error occurs when running addParameter() and it is thrown.So I want to know why this error,I checked the parameters used by addParameter() and found that there are no mistake.

Comment: In fact, running the program in the original environment does not error, but this problem occurs after the data modification of the database. I can't understand why the Axis encapsulation method will fail in this case.